# unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' for platform 'iphoneos' (in target 'watchVersion' from

Tags: flutter

i want to create flutter app for apple watch after Enabling bitcode in Xcode and Adding an Apple Watch target
but app is not running ,

get me this error

error: unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension' for platform 'iphoneos' (in target 'watchVersion Extension' from project 'Runner')

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your project's Xcode Build Settings for your Apple Watch app target (extension also) Base SDK and Supported platform to watchOS. Make sure that the Runner app stays on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is merging the extension and the app itself into a single target:

1. Go to errors in Xcode
2. Open the warning "Update to Recommended settings"
3. From there you will see an option to merge, click it and wait a while

Answer (score -2):

Faced a similar problem with Azure pipeline, the solution was to update sdk which was being passed as sdk:'iphoneos'.

Just passed empty string sdk: ''

Comment: Is there a chance you add a screenshot of your XCode configuration? It's madness to get around XCode to find the settings, hehe... Thanks a lot, @Amit!